# Spreadsheet Software (Javascript Funtions)

Tags: javascript, offline, google-apps, office, spreadsheet

*With Google Docs you're able to create GoogleScripts which allows to write Javascript Functions which you can use in Google Spreadsheet columns.*

**I looking for a spreadsheet application (offline) which allows to use Javascript-Functions in columns. (or JS-like syntax for functions)**

Reason: Dislike VBA/Macro-syntaxes and these snake-long build-in functions in columns.

I looking for something like that, but need it Offline.
Lost already data of some spreadsheets after holiday and sometimes Google Spreadsheets don't load properly and you've to wait until they fix the issue. (not good for work-files)

Would pay for such a software.

Comment: If Pyton is an option, see http://www.python-excel.org/ There is great support. ***But***, you won't access the Python with the spreadsheet open, just use it to read & create Excel files.  Worth looking into anyway

Answer (score 1):

If a programmatic solution is acceptable, a Spreadsheet control like [ejSpreadsheet](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/spreadsheet/) can be used to host your own spreadsheet locally that supports custom functions written in JS.

[Sample](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/c4hosdkv)

Note: I work for Syncfusion.